# Angular 8 not able to get Injector when test

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-test

I create one sample project in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdquuj) here. The sample project has 2 components(TestComponent and Test1Component), 1 service(TestService) and 1 class(Base) which TestComponent will extend.

There is one use case that i need to get service instance without using constructor, i am using below code and it works fine.

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,  TestComponent, Test1Component ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  exports: [TestComponent, Test1Component]
})
export class AppModule {
  static injector: Injector;
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    AppModule.injector = injector;
  }
}
```

And then in Base.ts.

```
export class Base {
  constructor() {
    console.log("i am base");
    let service = AppModule.injector.get(TestService); // with this i can get test service succesfully
  }
}
```

When I try to write test case for TestComponent, error throws, see below code, i don't know why this happen, please help... thanks.

```
describe("TestComponent", () => {
  // throws error, Error during loading: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'TestComponent' before initialization
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent); 
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My env:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.14
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.14
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.14
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.14
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.14
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.14
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.14
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.14
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.14
@schematics/angular               8.3.14
@schematics/update                0.803.14
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Answer (score 0):

- Update the `karma.config.js` to use `Angular-cli` as

  ```
  module.exports = function (config) {
      config.set({
      basePath: '',
       frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
       plugins: [
       require('karma-jasmine'),
       require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
       require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
       require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
       require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
     ],
  client:{
    clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
  },
  coverageIstanbulReporter: {
    reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
    fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
  },
  angularCli: {
    environment: 'dev'
  },
  reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
  port: 9876,
  colors: true,
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
  autoWatch: true,
  browsers: ['Chrome'],
  singleRun: false
  ```

  });
  };

The `Server Runner` is going to listen on the `port` **9876**

- Then import the types automatically using the types option in `tsconfig.json`:

`"types": ["jasmine"]`,

- Inside the `test.service.ts` it must contains the Specs imports

so to make the example works, just update `test.service.ts` and make it contain this line :

```
import './test/test.component.spec';
```

And for running Tests you should use a Test runner as `Karma` and not `Node` because it does not know about your test framework

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, actually i don't know how to run ng test in stackblitz that is only for code demo. I am using the ng cli to create the project in my local with the same code, but even i add the line you suggested, it still throws the same error in my local..

Comment: Could you please try this, and update the post by inserting a snapshot of the error message